# vim: str2float for integers

Tags: vim

vim users, is there a string to integer converter like str2float. I can very well use str2float to do it and later on use a regex to deal with the floating point zeros but life would be easy with something like str2int.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to convert "1" to 1?

Comment: Yes. I use that to run a vim regex which adds the number 5 to numbers matching regex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called `str2nr(expr, [base])`. And it's listed directly below `str2float` in help file.

Comment: You can also use a string as a number in math context.  `"123" + 1` is 124.